# Inject a Map<String, List<String>> using Spring's @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a properties file that contains a map with keys that each have multiple values, like below

```
//properties.yml
myMap:
  key1: value1, value2
  key2: value1, value2, value3
```

It is fairly easy to read `myMap` using a Spring properties class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyConfiguration {
  private Map<String, List<String>> myMap;

  public Map<String, List<String>> getMyMap() {
      return myMap;
  }

  public void setMyMap(Map<String, List<String>> myMap) {
      this.myMap = myMap;
  }
}
```

However this feels like a lot of code for a simple task. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same thing using Spring's `@Value` annotation? I've tried to get it to work without success, trying things like

```
@Value("${myMap}")
private Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

I think maybe it requires SPEL but I'm not sure how

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this without converting the Properties file to a `.properties` or quoting the map key-values?

Answer (score 4):

To Inject Map using @Value you can do (but maybe you need to modify your YAML):

```
@Value("#{${myMap}}")
private Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

However, It is encouraged to use @ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value (especially if you use YAML format, Spring boot uses SnakeYAML to parse YAML files)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

You don't need a setter when loading to the map:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MapProperties {

    private Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, List<String>> getMyMap() {
        return this.myMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: How should `myMap` look like if I have an `application.properties` file for the same structure?

Answer (score 3):

`@value` annotation does not support the `Relaxed binding` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value) and it only supports `SpEL evaluation`

> If you define a set of configuration keys for your own components, we recommend you group them in a POJO annotated with @ConfigurationProperties. You should also be aware that, since @Value does not support relaxed binding, it is not a good candidate if you need to provide the value by using environment variables.
>
> Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such expressions are not processed from application property files.

I will recommende to use `@ConfigurationProperties` [doc1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) [doc2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge)

**Example**

> For Map properties, you can bind with property values drawn from multiple sources. However, for the same property in multiple sources, the one with the highest priority is used. The following example exposes a Map from AcmeProperties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

private final Map<String, MyPojo> map = new HashMap<>();

public Map<String, MyPojo> getMap() {
    return this.map;
    }

 }
```

**yml**

```
acme:
  map:
   key1:
    name: my name 1
    description: my description 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
@Value("#{${myMap}}")
private Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

Then in application.properties file write it like this:

```
myMap={'key1':{'value1', 'value2'}, 'key2':{'value1', 'value2', 'value3'}}
```