# Initializing Map from application.propeties in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I want to initialize a class field by using Spring's `@Value` Annotation.

The class field has the type `Map<String, List<String>>`.

I have tried using Spring's Expression Language, but I must be doing something wrong because it throws the following error, while loading the Spring Application Context:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iWantToBeInitialized'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: 
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: 
EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'a'
```

This is the code for `MyConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("#{'${foo.bar.mymap}'}")
    Map<String, List<String>> iWantToBeInitialized;
    
}
```

This is the code for `application.properties`:

```
foo.bar.mymap=${baz.bub.other:{'a-key':{'a-value'},'b-key':{'b1-value','b2-value'},'c-key':{'c1-value'}}}
```

It looks like it begins parsing the `a` of the `a-key`, but it isn't able to figure out to parse a map from it.

I have tried searching and stumbeld over a couple of Spring mechanisms including defining a "Custom Property Something", but I could not figure out how to extrapolate the solution of those examples on to my specific usecase.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

---

**Update 1:**

I have tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068753/504060).

It leads to the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myMap'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: 
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1008E: Property or field 'value1' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

**Update 2:**

Follow up on [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068753/504060) mentioned in Update 1:

I edited the answer and it solved the problem in the fashion I was searching for.

Comment: There is simpler approach: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-inject-map

Comment: I do not want to use yaml.

Answer (score 1):

This expression works for me:

```
populate.map.content={{key1: {'value1', 'value1'}, key2: {'value2', 'value2'}, key3: {'value3', 'value3'}}
```

The logs show that `Map<String, List<String>> propertyname` is correctly initialized:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

follow code code snippet

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "xxx")
public class MyConfig {

   private Map<String, List<String>> iWantToBeInitialized;
    
}
```

```
application.yml
==================

xxx:
  iWantToBeInitialized:
    a-key:
      - a-value
    b-key:
      - b1-value
      - b2-value
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not use the yaml format. (i did not downvote, btw)

Comment: Application.property
=======================
    b-key=[b1-value, b2-value]     and you can use @Value annotation to map it

Comment: I have solved my problem already. BTW, i do not understand what you mean in your comment.